# Android fragment creation (does not apper)

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create Fragment completely programmaticaly. Here is my code. What should appear is OpenGL surface (colored in red) but it doesn't. What am i doing wrong?

**ActivityClass.java code**

```
GLSurfaceView glView = new GLSurfaceView(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity);
glView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
glView.setRenderer(new Renderer());
    
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity);
layout.setId(1000);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.height = 100;
params.width = 100;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(glView);
    
Fragment fragment = new FragmentClass();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().add(1000, fragment).commit();
```

**FragmentClass.java code**

```
public class FragmentClass extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(1000, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: where should the fragment get it's layout from? You create it in your activity but it is not added to the resources, what is impossible at runtime. you need to create a layout in your resources and then pass the data to the fragment and fill the layout there

Answer (score 0):

you'r id on line below shows were the fragment want to go and it's your fragment container (in to a layout with 1000ID)

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(1000, fragment).commit();
```

and in this one you are telling witch layout you want to be placed in your fragment container  (this is also a layout with 1000 ID)

```
        return inflater.inflate(1000, container, false);
```

the ID of these two should be different